# GridView with DataTable as source not autopaging or sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically I'm setting my datasource on my gridview to a datatable that I filled in manually. Is there a way to get the gridview to autopage and sort? When I try to go to another page on the gridview it gives me an exception saying that the paging event is not being caught (meaning I don't have a method for the event). I have allow paging set to true as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to implement `OnPageIndexChanging` event for paging , `OnSorting` event for sorting like :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" runat="server" />
```

and in code behind :

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        // sort expression
    }
```

you can refer to this [Example](http://forums.asp.net/post/1177923.aspx)

Comment: I did this, but whenever I try to change the page the control disappears.

Comment: what did you wrote in the pageload event ? I guess you wrote grid binding in `if(!IsPostBack)`

Comment: Yes that's a very common mistake people forget in ASP code to check for IsPostBack :P